# Assistance with a javascript error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, webpack

I recently upgraded to webpack 5.65.0. This broke @react-pdf/renderer. An [answer](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/1645) on GitHub Issue has the fix I am trying to implement. After trying the "fix" I am getting the exact same error as this SO [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68991617/htmlwebpackplugin-throwing-typeerror-cannot-read-property-hash-of-undefined-a) except the solution doesn't apply to me.

```
...../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1349
                hash.update(this.buildInfo.hash);
                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```json
// @remove-on-eject-begin
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */
// @remove-on-eject-end
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const resolve = require('resolve');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
const paths = require('./paths');
const modules = require('./modules');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const ModuleNotFoundPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleNotFoundPlugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin =
  process.env.TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR === 'true'
    ? require('react-dev-utils/ForkTsCheckerWarningWebpackPlugin')
    : require('react-dev-utils/ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin');
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');
// @remove-on-eject-begin
const getCacheIdentifier = require('react-dev-utils/getCacheIdentifier');
// @remove-on-eject-end
const createEnvironmentHash = require('./webpack/persistentCache/createEnvironmentHash');

// Source maps are resource heavy and can cause out of memory issue for large source files.
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';

const reactRefreshRuntimeEntry = require.resolve('react-refresh/runtime');
const reactRefreshWebpackPluginRuntimeEntry = require.resolve(
  '@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin'
);
const babelRuntimeEntry = require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app');
const babelRuntimeEntryHelpers = require.resolve(
  '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/assertThisInitialized',
  { paths: [babelRuntimeEntry] }
);
const babelRuntimeRegenerator = require.resolve('@babel/runtime/regenerator', {
  paths: [babelRuntimeEntry],
});

// Some apps do not need the benefits of saving a web request, so not inlining the chunk
// makes for a smoother build process.
const shouldInlineRuntimeChunk = process.env.INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK !== 'false';

const emitErrorsAsWarnings = process.env.ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS === 'true';
const disableESLintPlugin = process.env.DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN === 'true';

const imageInlineSizeLimit = parseInt(
  process.env.IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT || '10000'
);

// Check if TypeScript is setup
const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

// Check if Tailwind config exists
const useTailwind = fs.existsSync(
  path.join(paths.appPath, 'tailwind.config.js')
);

// Get the path to the uncompiled service worker (if it exists).
const swSrc = paths.swSrc;

// style files regexes
const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

const hasJsxRuntime = (() => {
  if (process.env.DISABLE_NEW_JSX_TRANSFORM === 'true') {
    return false;
  }

  try {
    require.resolve('react/jsx-runtime');
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
})();

// This is the production and development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience, fast rebuilds, and a minimal bundle.
module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';

  // Variable used for enabling profiling in Production
  // passed into alias object. Uses a flag if passed into the build command
  const isEnvProductionProfile =
    isEnvProduction && process.argv.includes('--profile');

  // We will provide `paths.publicUrlOrPath` to our app
  // as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
  // Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_URL%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_URL%xyz.
  // Get environment variables to inject into our app.
  const env = getClientEnvironment(paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1));

  const shouldUseReactRefresh = env.raw.FAST_REFRESH;

  // common function to get style loaders
  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        // css is located in `static/css`, use '../../' to locate index.html folder
        // in production `paths.publicUrlOrPath` can be a relative path
        options: paths.publicUrlOrPath.startsWith('.')
          ? { publicPath: '../../' }
          : {},
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: cssOptions,
      },
      {
        // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
        // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
        // package.json
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          postcssOptions: {
            // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
            // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
            ident: 'postcss',
            config: false,
            plugins: !useTailwind
              ? [
                  'postcss-flexbugs-fixes',
                  [
                    'postcss-preset-env',
                    {
                      autoprefixer: {
                        flexbox: 'no-2009',
                      },
                      stage: 3,
                    },
                  ],
                  // Adds PostCSS Normalize as the reset css with default options,
                  // so that it honors browserslist config in package.json
                  // which in turn let's users customize the target behavior as per their needs.
                  'postcss-normalize',
                ]
              : [
                  'tailwindcss',
                  'postcss-flexbugs-fixes',
                  [
                    'postcss-preset-env',
                    {
                      autoprefixer: {
                        flexbox: 'no-2009',
                      },
                      stage: 3,
                    },
                  ],
                ],
          },
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment,
        },
      },
    ].filter(Boolean);
    if (preProcessor) {
      loaders.push(
        {
          loader: require.resolve('resolve-url-loader'),
          options: {
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment,
            root: paths.appSrc,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
          },
        }
      );
    }
    return loaders;
  };

  return {
    target: ['browserslist'],
    mode: isEnvProduction ? 'production' : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
    // Stop compilation early in production
    bail: isEnvProduction,
    devtool: isEnvProduction
      ? shouldUseSourceMap
        ? 'source-map'
        : false
      : isEnvDevelopment && 'cheap-module-source-map',
    // These are the "entry points" to our application.
    // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
    entry: paths.appIndexJs,
    output: {
      // The build folder.
      path: paths.appBuild,
      // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
      pathinfo: isEnvDevelopment,
      // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
      // In development, it does not produce real files.
      filename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js',
      // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
      chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
      assetModuleFilename: 'static/media/[name].[hash][ext]',
      // webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
      // It requires a trailing slash, or the file assets will get an incorrect path.
      // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
      publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
      // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: isEnvProduction
        ? info =>
            path
              .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
              .replace(/\\/g, '/')
        : isEnvDevelopment &&
          (info => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/')),
    },
    cache: {
      type: 'filesystem',
      version: createEnvironmentHash(env.raw),
      cacheDirectory: paths.appWebpackCache,
      store: 'pack',
      buildDependencies: {
        defaultWebpack: ['webpack/lib/'],
        config: [__filename],
        tsconfig: [paths.appTsConfig, paths.appJsConfig].filter(f =>
          fs.existsSync(f)
        ),
      },
    },
    infrastructureLogging: {
      level: 'none',
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: isEnvProduction,
      minimizer: [
        // This is only used in production mode
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            parse: {
              // We want terser to parse ecma 8 code. However, we don't want it
              // to apply any minification steps that turns valid ecma 5 code
              // into invalid ecma 5 code. This is why the 'compress' and 'output'
              // sections only apply transformations that are ecma 5 safe
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4234
              ecma: 8,
            },
            compress: {
              ecma: 5,
              warnings: false,
              // Disabled because of an issue with Uglify breaking seemingly valid code:
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2376
              // Pending further investigation:
              // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2011
              comparisons: false,
              // Disabled because of an issue with Terser breaking valid code:
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5250
              // Pending further investigation:
              // https://github.com/terser-js/terser/issues/120
              inline: 2,
            },
            mangle: {
              safari10: true,
            },
            // Added for profiling in devtools
            keep_classnames: isEnvProductionProfile,
            keep_fnames: isEnvProductionProfile,
            output: {
              ecma: 5,
              comments: false,
              // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2488
              ascii_only: true,
            },
          },
        }),
        // This is only used in production mode
        new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      // This allows you to set a fallback for where webpack should look for modules.
      // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
      // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253
      modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
        modules.additionalModulePaths || []
      ),
      fallback: {
      process: require.resolve("process/browser"),
      zlib: require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      util: require.resolve("util"),
      buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),
      asset: require.resolve("assert"),
    },  
      
  //plugins: [
  //  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  //    Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
  //    process: "process/browser",
  //  }),
  //],


      // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
      // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
      // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/290
      // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
      // for React Native Web.
      extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
        .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
        .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
      alias: {
        // Support React Native Web
        // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
        'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        // Allows for better profiling with ReactDevTools
        ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
          'react-dom$': 'react-dom/profiling',
          'scheduler/tracing': 'scheduler/tracing-profiling',
        }),
        ...(modules.webpackAliases || {}),
      },
      plugins: [
        // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
        // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
        // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
        // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
        // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
        new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [
          paths.appPackageJson,
          reactRefreshRuntimeEntry,
          reactRefreshWebpackPluginRuntimeEntry,
          babelRuntimeEntry,
          babelRuntimeEntryHelpers,
          babelRuntimeRegenerator,
        ]), 
          new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
              Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
              process: "process/browser",
          }),
      ],
    },
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        // Handle node_modules packages that contain sourcemaps
        shouldUseSourceMap && {
          enforce: 'pre',
          exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
          test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx|css)$/,
          loader: require.resolve('source-map-loader'),
        },
        {
          // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
          // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
          // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
          oneOf: [
            // TODO: Merge this config once `image/avif` is in the mime-db
            // https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db
            {
              test: [/\.avif$/],
              type: 'asset',
              mimetype: 'image/avif',
              parser: {
                dataUrlCondition: {
                  maxSize: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                },
              },
            },
            // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
            // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
            // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              type: 'asset',
              parser: {
                dataUrlCondition: {
                  maxSize: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                },
              },
            },
            {
              test: /\.svg$/,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: require.resolve('@svgr/webpack'),
                  options: {
                    prettier: false,
                    svgo: false,
                    svgoConfig: {
                      plugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
                    },
                    titleProp: true,
                    ref: true,
                  },
                },
                {
                  loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
                  options: {
                    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash].[ext]',
                  },
                },
              ],
              issuer: {
                and: [/\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx|md|mdx)$/],
              },
            },
            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appSrc,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
                ),
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app'),
                    {
                      runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? 'automatic' : 'classic',
                    },
                  ],
                ],
                // @remove-on-eject-begin
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                // Make sure we have a unique cache identifier, erring on the
                // side of caution.
                // We remove this when the user ejects because the default
                // is sane and uses Babel options. Instead of options, we use
                // the react-scripts and babel-preset-react-app versions.
                cacheIdentifier: getCacheIdentifier(
                  isEnvProduction
                    ? 'production'
                    : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
                  [
                    'babel-plugin-named-asset-import',
                    'babel-preset-react-app',
                    'react-dev-utils',
                    'react-scripts',
                  ]
                ),
                // @remove-on-eject-end
                plugins: [
                  isEnvDevelopment &&
                    shouldUseReactRefresh &&
                    require.resolve('react-refresh/babel'),
                ].filter(Boolean),
                // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                // directory for faster rebuilds.
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                compact: isEnvProduction,
              },
            },
            // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
            // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                    { helpers: true },
                  ],
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                // @remove-on-eject-begin
                cacheIdentifier: getCacheIdentifier(
                  isEnvProduction
                    ? 'production'
                    : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
                  [
                    'babel-plugin-named-asset-import',
                    'babel-preset-react-app',
                    'react-dev-utils',
                    'react-scripts',
                  ]
                ),
                // @remove-on-eject-end
                // Babel sourcemaps are needed for debugging into node_modules
                // code.  Without the options below, debuggers like VSCode
                // show incorrect code and set breakpoints on the wrong lines.
                sourceMaps: shouldUseSourceMap,
                inputSourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
              },
            },
            // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
            // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
            // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
            // In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
            // to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
            // of CSS.
            // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                  ? shouldUseSourceMap
                  : isEnvDevelopment,
                modules: {
                  mode: 'icss',
                },
              }),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
            // using the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                  ? shouldUseSourceMap
                  : isEnvDevelopment,
                modules: {
                  mode: 'local',
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                },
              }),
            },
            // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
            // By default we support SASS Modules with the
            // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                    ? shouldUseSourceMap
                    : isEnvDevelopment,
                  modules: {
                    mode: 'icss',
                  },
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
            // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                    ? shouldUseSourceMap
                    : isEnvDevelopment,
                  modules: {
                    mode: 'local',
                    getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                  },
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
            },
            // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
            // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
            // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
            // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
            // that fall through the other loaders.
            {
              // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
              // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
              // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
              // by webpacks internal loaders.
              exclude: [/^$/, /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
            // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
          ],
        },
      ].filter(Boolean),
    },
    plugins: [
      // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
          },
          isEnvProduction
            ? {
                minify: {
                  removeComments: true,
                  collapseWhitespace: true,
                  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                  useShortDoctype: true,
                  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                  keepClosingSlash: true,
                  minifyJS: true,
                  minifyCSS: true,
                  minifyURLs: true,
                },
              }
            : undefined
        )
      ),
    [...]
```

I have fat-fingered something more than a few times but I can't find it here. The revelent code I just added is in `module.exports>resolve>fallback` and `module.exports>resolve>plugins`. Any tip or help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's one big code block!

Answer (score 0):

```
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
```

I think this peace of code is wrong

```
because { WebpackManifestPlugin } is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have put the plugins object in the same level as the "resolve.fallback". Try to put it outside the resolve (it should be at the same level with resolve".

For example:

Not like this:

```
 {
    ...
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            ...
        },
        plugins: {
            ...
        }
        ...
     },
     ...
}
```

Should be like this:

```
{
    ...
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            ...
        }
    },
    ...,
    plugins: {
        //your code here
    }
}
```